# How do I blur the right and left sides of a scroll container?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make the left and right sides of the container have a blur effect using the `box-shadow` property. The container (`boxes`) contains what boxes are currently in view as there are multiple boxes in that container that can be scrolled through using 2 buttons (with ids `backwards` and `forwards`.

How do I add a fading blur effect to the edges of the container? The far edges shouldn't be visible and then it should gradually get lighter.

Example:

[image: Example]

vs mine:

[image: mine]

html:

```
<div class="boxes-container">
    <div class="boxes">
        <!-- box 1 -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/b6005f78-45e6-403a-bc1d-3351ae83d149.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <h6>Why host on Airbnb?</h6>
            <p>Hosts reveal what they love about sharing their space on Airbnb.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- box 2 -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/9ac19f4a-a59c-47f9-8223-09120b52cd2d.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <h6>How to get started on Airbnb</h6>
            <p>From creating your listing to prepping your space, learn how to start hosting.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- box 3 -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/4d0cc0ed-ad85-4efd-b98e-386d22ab195a.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <h6>How to earn money on Airbnb</h6>
            <p>Here's what every Host needs to know about pricing and payouts.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- box 4 -->
        <div class="box">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/4efaca33-ca90-4d94-a79b-381cf0179355.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <h6>Designing your space</h6>
            <p>Designing your space for guests can be a quick way to boost your bookings.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- box 5 -->
        <div class="box" id="last-box">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/3cea79b0-79c3-4604-8fd9-7ef5cee4aa42.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <h6>Secrets from a seasoned Superhost</h6>
            <p>Superhost Nikki shares her tips, from setting up to standing out.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.boxes-container {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.boxes {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    // border: 2px solid red;
    position: relative;

    &::before, &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 2rem;
        height: 100%;
    }

    &::before {
        box-shadow: 50px 0 50px #fff inset;
        left: 0;
    }

    &::after {
        box-shadow: -50px 0 50px #fff inset;
        // box-shadow: -80px 0 #fff inset;
        right: 0;
    }
    
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none}

    .box {
        @include flexCenter(column);
        align-items: flex-start;
        gap: 1rem;
        width: 332px;
        max-width: 332px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 2rem;
        // background-color: green;

        &#last-box {
            padding-right: 2rem;
        }

        .img-container {
            
            img {
                width: 322px;
                max-width: 322px;
                height: 200px;
                object-fit: cover;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
        }

        h6 {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 14.5px;
            font-weight: lighter;
            letter-spacing: 0.1px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I add the javascript I used for the buttons as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mask. Here is simplified example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(90deg,#0000,#000 10% 80%,#0000)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/150">
</div>
```